# Using QQmlContext::setContextObject to make a C++ object visible to QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

**Edit:** Problem solved. See my edit below

I am having trouble using QQmlContext::setContextObject to make a C++ object visible to QML. I have read the documentation for QQmlContext at [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qqmlcontext.html#details), which suggests that I can use setContextObject to make the Q_PROPERTY's of a QObject-derived class visible to QML. The following code illustrates the problem.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QGuiApplication>

class MyClass : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_PROPERTY(QString myProperty READ prop NOTIFY propChanged)

public:
   MyClass(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}
   QString prop() { return QString("Hello from MyClass"); }

Q_SIGNALS:
   void propChanged(void);
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

   QQmlEngine engine;
   QQmlContext *objectContext = new QQmlContext(engine.rootContext());
   MyClass myClass;
   objectContext->setContextObject(&myClass);

   QQmlComponent component(&engine, "main.qml");
   QObject *object = component.create(objectContext);

   return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

ApplicationWindow
{
   Text
   {
      text: myProperty
   }
}
```

When I run this program I get the error

```
file:///C:/Path/to/main.qml:8: ReferenceError: myProperty is not defined
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Environment. I am using Qt 5.1.1 on Windows 7, with MSVC2010 compiler

---

**Edit.** Answering my own question. A clean rebuild showed that my build output folder clearly had some out-of-date objects in it.

One point of note: MyClass has to be in a separate file, or else the moc compiler cannot do its magic.

My tidied-up main.cpp now looks like this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

   QQmlEngine engine;
   QQmlContext * context = new QQmlContext(engine.rootContext());

   QObject::connect(&engine, SIGNAL(quit()), QCoreApplication::instance(), SLOT(quit    ()));

   MyClass myClass;
   context->setContextObject(&myClass);

   QQmlComponent component(&engine, "main.qml");
   QQuickWindow * topLevel = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(component.create(context));
   topLevel->show();

   int rc = app.exec();

   delete topLevel;
   delete context;
   return rc;
}
```

Comment: A note for anyone else who reads this: you can have QObject-derived classes in main.cpp, you just need to add `#include "main.moc"` to the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add `Q_INVOKABLE` macro in you getter function decalration. If it will not help you can consider using `QQmlContext::setContextProperty` to do this. I have never seen that somebody is doing this kind of integration using `::setContextObject`.

Comment: Adding the Q_INVOKABLE macro did not help, nor did setContextProperty. I admit that I do not normally use setContextObject, either. I am writing a small utility program and I wanted to avoid having to put MyClass into a separate components dll.

Comment: `setContextProperty` _should_ work. Can u double check that you do `setContextProperty(QString("name"))` and `name.myProperty` in C++ and QML respectively?

Comment: setContextProperty and setContextObject both now work. I did a clean rebuild of my entire project tree, which showed a number of syntax errors that were not identified before. It seems that before I did the clean build, the code in the editor did not match the code that was being run. I will accept your answer, thank you for your help.